# Map multiple arrays at the same time javascript/reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this array of objects in my calendar project:

```
const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState({});

const [weekday,setWeekDays] = useState([ 
  {name: 'Su',sortedDays:[{dayNum:1,chosen:false}]},
  {name: 'Mo',sortedDays:[{dayNum:21,chosen:false}},
  {name: 'Tu',sortedDays:[{dayNum:15,chosen:false}},
  {name: 'We',sortedDays:[{dayNum:11,chosen:false}},
  {name: 'Th',sortedDays:[{dayNum:23,chosen:false}},
  {name: 'Fr',sortedDays:[{dayNum:31,chosen:false}},
  {name: 'Sa',sortedDays:[{dayNum:30,chosen:false}},
])
```

***What I'm doing***

I am mapping this array as buttons and give users ability to select the day on calendar

***What I'm trying to achieve***

Whenever user clicks on the button, the selected button must change background color.

***What I tried***

First I tried to make this work like this:

```
const selectWeekDay = (child, info) => {
const updateSortedDays = info.sortedDays.map((day) =>
  day.dayNum === child.dayNum
    ? {...day, chosen: !day.chosen}
    : {...day, chosen: false},
);

const updatedWeekDay = weekday.map((el) => {
  return el.name === info.name ? {...el, sortedDays: updateSortedDays} : el;
});

setWeekDays(updatedWeekDay);
};
```

And it worked but the issue was that it was not working on every array inside my array of objects.

So I tried to change it like this:

```
 const updateWeekDays = () => {
let x = [...weekday];
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].sortedDays.map((day) =>
    selectedDay.dayNum === day.dayNum
      ? {...day, chosen: true}
      : {...day, chosen: false},
  );
}
return x;
};
```

I am calling this function in `useEffect` only after this validation:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (selectedDay.dayNum) {
  setWeekDays(updateWeekDays());
}
  }, [selectedDay]);
```

But sadly this workaround is not working and I don't understand why.

Any suggestions please?

***DEMO:***

https://replit.com/@NikitaZotsik/MultipleArrayMap#index.js

Comment: Can you please share working demo of your problem?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela Sure,I will create it right now

Comment: @PriyankKachhela https://replit.com/@NikitaZotsik/MultipleArrayMap#index.js

Comment: Array map won't modify what it's being called on, so `x[i].sortedDays.map( ... )` won't change anything without assigning that back to x[i].sortedDays https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your `updateWeekDays` function like below:-

```
  const updateWeekDays = () => {
    const copyWeekDay = [...weekday];
    return copyWeekDay.map(week => {
      week.sortedDays = week.sortedDays.map(day => {
        if (day.dayNum === selectedDay.dayNum) {
          day.chosen = !day.chosen;
        }
        return day;
      });
      return week;
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React


const App = () => {
  const chooseDay = (days, dayName) => {
    const result = [...days]
    result.forEach(day => day.sortedDays[0].chosen = false);
    const dayToChange = result.find(({ name }) => name === dayName)
    dayToChange.sortedDays[0].chosen = true;
    return result;
  }
  const [weekDays,setWeekDays] = useState([ 
    {name: 'Su',sortedDays:[{dayNum:1,chosen:false}]},
    {name: 'Mo',sortedDays:[{dayNum:21,chosen:false}]},
    {name: 'Tu',sortedDays:[{dayNum:15,chosen:false}]},
    {name: 'We',sortedDays:[{dayNum:11,chosen:false}]},
    {name: 'Th',sortedDays:[{dayNum:23,chosen:false}]},
    {name: 'Fr',sortedDays:[{dayNum:31,chosen:false}]},
    {name: 'Sa',sortedDays:[{dayNum:30,chosen:false}]},
  ])

  return <div>
    {weekDays.map(
      ({ name, sortedDays: [{dayNum, chosen}] }) => 
        <button
          key={name}
          style={{ backgroundColor: chosen && 'green' }} 
          onClick={() => setWeekDays(chooseDay(weekDays, name))}>
          { name }
        </button>  
    )}
    </div>
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , app);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id=app>
```